# Setting an <a href> as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, web-applications

I'm working on a web app where I'm using an object array to declare values that I will print out using `<p ng-repeat="var game in download.game">{{value}}, {{value}}</p>`and so on.

I also wanted to use a download button for the user to download the files. But using a normal `a` element, I could only add one link to a specific file. So I was wondering how I could assign a *variable* to my link so that I could instead have {{download-link}}.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Declare a variable, insert a string, declare the `.src` attribute of the `<a>` as the variable. If it's possible, that's how you'd do it. It's in your hands now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Controller :

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    link: "http://link.com",
    text: "link.com"
  },
  {
    link: "http://link1.com",
    text: "link1.com"
  },
  {
    link: "http://link2.com",
    text: "link2.com"
  }
];
```

View :

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data">
  <a href="{{element.link}}">{{element.text}}</a>
</div>
```

Codepen :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGZrMm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the question right but try something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="var game in download.game">
  <a ng-href="{{game.link}}">{{game.value1}}, {{game.value2}}</a>
</div>
```

Being `game.link` and the other variables the variables you want to print.

You should try to avoid printing `Angular` variables into **non-angular** attributes. So try to use `ng-href`, `ng-click` and the likes.